# C++: debug bus error

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am trying to compile a c++ program in Linux, using the command in the shell

```
$ g++ -Wall *.cpp -o prog
```

and for some reason it keeps on giving me a weird error:

> g++: Internal error: Bus error (program cc1plus) Please submit a full
>   bug report. See  for
>   instructions.

I searched the net for this bus error, and it says that it has to do with something about accessing illegal memory.

Can someone maybe clarify things a bit more for me?

Comment: Does that happen only on these specific *.cpp files, or does it happen whenever you are trying to compile something? If it's the latter then it could be an error in your Linux installation, otherwise you found a g++ bug.

Comment: Also, what g++ version are you using (see `g++ -v`)? And does it happen with other versions too?

Answer (score 6):

This error message is telling you that there's a bug in the g++ compiler itself.

Try to narrow it down by removing bits and pieces of your source file until the problem goes away.  You're not trying to fix your program, you're just trying to find the part that is breaking the compiler. Once you've found it, you can either give a better bug description or you can change your code to work around it.

Or just download the latest version of the g++ compiler and hope that it's already fixed.

Comment: What if repeated attempts to recompile (without **any** changes to the source code) eventually cause the compiler to succeed?

Comment: @KyleStrand, that's certainly possible, and it's a strong indication that the compiler has an uninitialized variable bug. My advice remains the same, although it makes it harder to tell when your own code modifications make a difference.

Comment: Hmmm. That is odd, because I'm using 5.1, which is *pretty* recent....and it also consistently builds correctly on multiple other machines. I sort of suspect I've inadvertently done something weird to the filesystem on the machine itself, or something.

Comment: @KyleStrand perhaps the computer has a spot of bad RAM?

Comment: Memtest found no errors. Fortunately, we apparently have some spare systems we just haven't had time to set up yet, so I may be able to put this issue aside indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not in your code, is the compiler (g++) that is crashing and producing that Bus Error, it's possible you have an outdated version of such compiler and need to update, or you're lucky and found a real bug in g++.

I would try compiling each source file separately, to check what part of the source code triggers the error.